# How to count number of lines for a specific file type in a tgz compressed file?

Tags: text-processing, grep, find, archive

I saw below post which helps me in getting the total number of lines in each .tgz file but I want to count only number of lines of .js files in this compressed .tgz folders not everything. How do I do it?

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22064932/count-number-of-lines-of-gz-files-recursviely-on-directory

Answer (score 1):

You want to extract all the files matching `*.js` to stdout and use `wc -l` to count the lines:

```
tar -x -f file.tgz -O --wildcards '*.js' | wc -l
```

`-O` outputs to stdout instead of writing files to disk (as tar normally does).

`--wildcards` lets you use wildcards in the filenames that are extracted (and this is likely GNU only, although on Linux this is what you'll have).

That will do a single tar file. If you have multiple, you can do it in a loop and pipe the output of a loop to `wc -l`.

Answer (score 1):

To get the line count of each `.js` file in a compressed tar archive, try:

```
tar -xf file.tgz --to-command='echo " $TAR_FILENAME $(wc -l)"' --wildcards '*.js'
```

As a demonstration, let's start with this archive:

```
$ tar --list -f file.tgz
a.js
dir1/
dir1/b.js
other.txt
```

Now, let's get the line count for each js file in the archive:

```
$ tar -xf file.tgz --to-command='echo " $TAR_FILENAME $(wc -l)"' --wildcards '*.js' 
 a.js 10
 dir1/b.js 15
```

#### Improvement

If we want nicer formating of the output, we can use `printf` instead of `echo`:

```
$ tar -xf file.tgz --to-command='printf "%-10s %s\n" "$TAR_FILENAME" "$(wc -l)"' --wildcards '*.js' 
a.js       10
dir1/b.js  15
```

#### How it works

- `-x` tells tar to extract files.
- `-f file.tgz` tells tar to extract from `file.tgz`.
- `--to-command='echo "$TAR_FILENAME $(wc -l)"'` tells tar to apply this command to each extracted file.  Tar provides the name of each file in the environment variable `$TAR_FILENAME`.
- `--wildcards` tells tar to chose the files to extract using a glob.
- `'*.js'` specifies the file glob to extract.